# OpenGL layer goes black on presentRenderBuffer

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es

I have a kids drawing app that works fine on iOS 6 and 7. Nowadays trying how the app works on iOS 8.1 I found only a bug.

Drawing context is correctly initialized, but when I draw a line, suddenly the background goes black (instead of the white one default) but the line is correctly drawn, with the different shaders I use (pencil, brush, marker...)

Here is the code where the screen goes black

```
- (void)renderLineFromPoint:(CGPoint)start toPoint:(CGPoint)end 
{
static GLfloat*     vertexBuffer = NULL;
static NSUInteger   vertexMax = 64;
NSUInteger          vertexCount = 0,
count,
i;

[EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context];
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, viewFramebuffer);

// Convert locations from Points to Pixels
CGFloat scale = self.contentScaleFactor;
start.x *= scale;
start.y *= scale;
end.x *= scale;
end.y *= scale;

// Allocate vertex array buffer
if(vertexBuffer == NULL)
    vertexBuffer = malloc(vertexMax * 2 * sizeof(GLfloat));

// Add points to the buffer so there are drawing points every X pixels
count = MAX(ceilf(sqrtf((end.x - start.x) * (end.x - start.x) + (end.y - start.y) * (end.y - start.y)) / kBrushPixelStep), 1);
for(i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    if(vertexCount == vertexMax) {
        vertexMax = 2 * vertexMax;
        vertexBuffer = realloc(vertexBuffer, vertexMax * 2 * sizeof(GLfloat));
    }

    vertexBuffer[2 * vertexCount + 0] = start.x + (end.x - start.x) * ((GLfloat)i / (GLfloat)count);
    vertexBuffer[2 * vertexCount + 1] = start.y + (end.y - start.y) * ((GLfloat)i / (GLfloat)count);
    vertexCount += 1;
}

// Load data to the Vertex Buffer Object
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboId);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexCount*2*sizeof(GLfloat), vertexBuffer, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_VERTEX);
glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIB_VERTEX, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

// Draw
// glUseProgram(program[PROGRAM_POINT].id);
glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, vertexCount);

// Display the buffer
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, viewRenderbuffer);
[context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER];

self.mustSave = YES;
}
```

And this is the initGL code

```
- (BOOL)initGL
{
// Generate IDs for a framebuffer object and a color renderbuffer
glGenFramebuffers(1, &viewFramebuffer);
glGenRenderbuffers(1, &viewRenderbuffer);

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, viewFramebuffer);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, viewRenderbuffer);
// This call associates the storage for the current render buffer with the EAGLDrawable (our CAEAGLLayer)
// allowing us to draw into a buffer that will later be rendered to screen wherever the layer is (which corresponds with our view).
[context renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER fromDrawable:(id<EAGLDrawable>)self.layer];
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, viewRenderbuffer);

glGetRenderbufferParameteriv(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH, &backingWidth);
glGetRenderbufferParameteriv(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT, &backingHeight);

// For this sample, we do not need a depth buffer. If you do, this is how you can create one and attach it to the framebuffer:
//    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &depthRenderbuffer);
//    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthRenderbuffer);
//    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, backingWidth, backingHeight);
//    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthRenderbuffer);

if(glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
{
    NSLog(@"failed to make complete framebuffer object %x", glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER));
    return NO;
}

// Setup the view port in Pixels
glViewport(0, 0, backingWidth, backingHeight);

// Create a Vertex Buffer Object to hold our data
glGenBuffers(1, &vboId);

// Load the brush texture
brushTexture = [self textureFromName:kStrokePatternPencil];

// Load shaders
[self setupShaders];

// Enable blending and set a blending function appropriate for premultiplied alpha pixel data
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

return YES;
}
```

Is there any issue with iOS 8 that I'm ignoring?

Answer (score 1):

Given that you are not calling glClear I'm taking a guess that you are expecting the contents of your framebuffer to be preserved across frames. In OpenGL ES on iOS this is not always the case and it can depend on the GPU and version of iOS. When the framebuffer is not preserved, it would go black as you describe.

See this link: [Working with EAGLContexts](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/WorkingwithEAGLContexts/WorkingwithEAGLContexts.html). Specifically the section titled: 'Present the Results to Core Animation'

If you are using CAEAGLLayer to render your OpenGL ES content, then you can set the retained property like this:

```
eaglLayer.drawableProperties = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [NSNumber numberWithBool:TRUE], kEAGLDrawablePropertyRetainedBacking, kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8, kEAGLDrawablePropertyColorFormat, nil];
```

(the important part is that kEAGLDrawablePropertyRetainedBacking is set to true)

Comment: And if you do enable retained backing, you take a significant performance hit on mobile GPUs. It's usually better to architect your renderer such that it can redraw the whole scene on every frame.

Comment: Sorry, I avoid pasting the initGL method in which I init the context with this properties, but I'm doing it.